# Help with Proof of Hartogs Sierpinski Theorem

Tags: set-theory

I would be grateful if someone could help me in the understanding of Theorem 1 in [this](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Gillman544-553.pdf) article.

The line I am having problem with is "The segment of $E$ determined by $K$ is then similar to $S$", which, after drawing diagrams and thinking about if for a while I am not getting.

This is a summary of the proof to that point:
Let $M$ be an infinite set. Let $W$ be the set of subsets of $M$ which are well-ordered by set inclusion. Each set in $W$ when ordered by inclusion has  an order type. Partition $W$ into sets which have the same order type, to form the set $E$. Associated with each set in $E$ is an ordinal (the order type of each of the members in the set); Order the members of $E$  by the natural ordinal ordering. We claim $E$ is not dominated by $M$. Assume the contrary, that is $E$ is dominated by $M$. Then $E$ is equipotent to a subset of $M$, say $M_1$. Let $S$ be the set of segments of $M_1$. Then by some obvious isomorphisms, the order type of $E$ (when ordered by the natural ordinal ordering) is the same as the order type of $M_1$ when ordered by the order induced by $E$ is the same as the order type of $S$ when ordered by of inclusion. And as $S$ is a set of subsets of $M$ and is well ordered by inclusion, then it is a member of $W$ and so it is a member of one of the sets of $E$, say $K$. **And the segment of $E$ determined by $K$ is then similar to $S$.**

The segment of $E$ determined by $K$ is the set of equivalence classes in $E$ associated with ordinals less than the order type of $S$. Why should that be similar to $S$? I guess to show the similarity I need to find an order embedding bijection between this set and $S$?